# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission error

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am getting following error

> Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission,
>   System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.

while using SQL connection in sandboxed solution in SharePoint 2010. I edited WSS_Minimal file, tried with `Trust Level="Full"`. But still not able to rectify the error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance
Anoop Thomas

---

I m using custom database. Here also I tried with keeping the database in another server and same server also.

Comment: Are you trying to hit a SharePoint database or a custom database specific to your application?

Answer (score 0):

**http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chunliu/archive/2010/08/26/accessing-databases-in-a-sandboxed-solution.aspx**

Refer this..

It solved my problem..